# how can I call an @viewchild from a provider?

Tags: angular

I Am using angular 9 and this is my stage. I am using a framework called `mdbootstrap`, among its functionalities I can create `modals` in the following way in any `template component`:

```
<button type="button" mdbBtn color="default" rounded="true" data-toggle="modal" data-
(click)="frame.show()" mdbWavesEffect>Launch Modal</button>
<!-- click on the button, opens my modal-->!

<div mdbModal #frame="mdbModal" class="modal fade top" id="frameModalTop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
....
</div>
```

I can click the button to open the modal `(click)="frame.show()"` or from the component I can put this to open it:

```
@ViewChild("frame") frame: any
 .
 .
 .
this.frame.show();
```

so I have created a component called `mymodalComponent` whit this selector: `<mymodal>` with the previous content:

```
<mymodal #modal></mymodal>
```

content of `<mymodal #modal></mymodal>`:

```
<div mdbModal #frame="mdbModal" class="modal fade top" id="frameModalTop" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
....
</div>
```

I have this provider:

```
@Injectable()
 export class ServicesProvider implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChild("modal") modal: any;
  constructor(){
  }
  openModal(){
    this.modal.frame.show();
  }
}
```

And my idea is to call this modal when I execute the `openModal()` function, I would put `<mymodal #modal> </mymodal>` in the template of `app.component.html`, but this line of function `openModal()` appears as `undefined`.

```
this.modal.frame.show();  //this.modal is undefined
```

How can i fix it?

I want that every time I execute the `servicesProvider.openModal()` function when called in a component my modal will open

**In summary**

I have put `<mymodal #modal> </mymodal>` in `app.component.html`(I don't know if it's the best way) and in `app.module.ts` I have imported it in declarations.

I simply want that when I call a function from a provider like: `servicesProvider.openModal()`, the modal is generated, but I don't know how to call `frame.show()` from the provider, `this.modal` in `servicesProvider` is `undefined`

Comment: @A.khalifa I am using angular 9

Comment: The behavior of a `ViewChild()` decorator doesn't apply except in `Component` or `Directive` or definitions.

Comment: @AluanHaddad So what can I do to fulfill what I need? can you advise me something please?

Comment: There are many approaches out there. For example the popular ng-bootstrap library uses [this code](https://github.com/ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap/blob/master/src/modal/modal-stack.ts#L50). Generally speaking, you must pass enough information about the modal to your service in order for it to create create and open on. If you want an implicitly passed modal, there are ways that might work but it will be complex. Get the basic idea, `servicesProvider.openModal(templateReference)` to work

Comment: @AluanHaddad Thanks, I know that, but with this framework I don't see how to do it .. I have tried to import said component into my provider. I don't know if it's a good idea (and if it were, I don't know how to access any property of the modal component)

Comment: That library is making it hard for me to see the Angular documentation. Does it want me to pay to read that?

Comment: @AluanHaddad Friend I appreciate the help, from what I see the only way to do it is doing it with the paid version, but for legal reasons I can't do it. I hope someone will help me so that tomorrow this question can help another user ... I know that you cannot use the modal in the conventional way as boostrap would, so I would like to know about another good solution.

Comment: If you yourself don't have a paid license, I would advise that you use a different component library, such as @ng-bootstrap, @angular/material, or one of many others.

Comment: @AluanHaddad I don't know if you know how to call a function or variable of a component once I have imported it into my provider.

Comment: You might be able to create an injector that uses a custom provider to inject the component into the service (what you're calling a provider is not a provider but a service). However, the simple thing to do is pass the component instance to the service that opens the modal. I.e.: `Component A {@ViewChild('frame') frame; openModal() {this.serivce.openModal(this.frame)}  }`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221755/discussion-between-yavg-and-aluan-haddad).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to implement:

```
app.component.html
<button type="button" mdbBtn color="primary" class="relative waves-light" (click)="showModal()" mdbWavesEffect>Launch demo modal</button>

app.component.ts
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ModalComponent } from './modal/modal.component';
import { MDBModalRef, MDBModalService } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  title = 'mdb-angular-free';
  modalRef: MDBModalRef;

  constructor(
    private modalService: MDBModalService
  ) {}

  showModal() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ModalComponent, {})
    this.modalRef.content.action
        .subscribe((result: any) => {
          if (result === 'yes') {
              console.log('YES');
          }
    });
  }
}

modal.component.html
<div class="modal-content text-center">
  <div class="custom-modal modal-dialog modal-notify m-0"> 
    <div class="modal-header justify-content-center">
      <p class="heading">TITLE</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
      <mdb-icon fas icon="close" size="4x" class="animated rotateIn"></mdb-icon>
      <p>MODAL</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer justify-content-center">
      <button type="button" mdbBtn color="danger" class="waves-effect" aria-label="Закрыть" (click)="onNoClick()" mdbWavesEffect>Нет</button>
      <button type="button" mdbBtn color="danger" class="relative waves-effect" outline="true" (click)="onYesClick()" mdbWavesEffect>Да</button>
    </div>
  </div>  
</div>

modal.component.ts
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { MDBModalRef } from 'angular-bootstrap-md';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-modal',
  templateUrl: './modal.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./modal.component.scss']
})
export class ModalComponent implements OnInit {

  action: Subject<any> = new Subject();

  constructor(public modalRef: MDBModalRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  onYesClick() {
    this.action.next('yes');
  }

  onNoClick() {
      this.modalRef.hide();
      this.action.next('no');
  }
}
```

Comment: You are very kind to share your code, but I have the free version, due to legal issues where I work, the pro license cannot be purchased, so I cannot have `MDBModalRef ` 
 (`import { MDBModalRef } from 'ng-uikit-pro-standard'`);

Comment: You can import { MDBModalRef } from 'angular-bootstrap-md' - it's free and work fine too. You selected a hard way and I'm not sure that it possible implement for mdbootstrap

Comment: I edited my answer with using free mdbootstrap version